# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for MVC file(image) upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am new to MVC, I was following a tutorial and got this error

[image: Image Here]

I followed the every steps in the tutorial, but still getting the same error
Here is the code for my view

```
@model _234CrudDemo.Models.ComplaintTicket

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ComplaintTicket</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attachment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ministry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ministry, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ministry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller

```
public class ComplaintTicketController : Controller
{
    //CRUDDataComplaintsEntities db = new CRUDDataComplaintsEntities();
    //// GET: ComplaintTicket
    //public ActionResult Index()
    //{
    //    //var tickets = db.ComplaintsTickets.ToList();
    //    var tickets = (from x in db.ComplaintTicket
    //                   join a in db.mins on x.Ministry equals a.Id
    //                   select new TicketsIndexLists() { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, Message = x.Message, Attachment = x.Attachment, Name = a.Name }).ToList();
    //    return View(tickets);
    //}
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(ComplaintTicket imageModel)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
        fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        imageModel.Attachment = "~/Image/" + fileName;
        fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
        imageModel.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
        //db.ComplaintTicket.Add(imageModel);
        //db.SaveChanges();
        //ModelState.Clear();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my model class

```
public partial class ComplaintTicket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
    public string Attachment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Ministry { get; set; }

    public virtual mins mins { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

Please how do I resolve this, I have search for solutions here and try answers given to 
previous similar questions, but none worked for, its still giving me the same error, help needed.
Am new to c#
Thanks

Comment: @SimplyGed No, I tried the solutions

Comment: imageModel --- most likely its null. Check value and path and you'll get it working.

Comment: @Jawad Please explain better, I don't understand

Comment: In your controller, this line is causing your NullReferenceExceptions... string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
    You need to check why imageModel is null

Comment: @YahbuezeMannesseh In your HTML code, you never assign a value to the `ImageFile` property and when your controller tries to access that property with the line `string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);` the `ImageFile` property is null - which produces the error you are seeing. Please re-read the original link as that has the best advice on how to fix a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have did few modification in your code, you can refer that and try on your end. Basically you need to take care few conditional approach for directory exists or not as well object referece null or not.

I have update you code with all aspect. Even you need to use **enctype="multipart/form-data"** while you post the image to controller, otherwise file object will remain null always.

Let me know in case of anything else required.

> .cshtml Code

```
@model _234CrudDemo.Models.ComplaintTicket

<form method="post" action="@Url.Action(" Add ")" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ComplaintTicket</h4>
    <hr /> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attachment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ministry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ministry, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ministry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Controller Code

```
public class ComplaintTicketController : Controller
{
    //CRUDDataComplaintsEntities db = new CRUDDataComplaintsEntities();
    //// GET: ComplaintTicket
    //public ActionResult Index()
    //{
    //    //var tickets = db.ComplaintsTickets.ToList();
    //    var tickets = (from x in db.ComplaintTicket
    //                   join a in db.mins on x.Ministry equals a.Id
    //                   select new TicketsIndexLists() { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, Message = x.Message, Attachment = x.Attachment, Name = a.Name }).ToList();
    //    return View(tickets);
    //}
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(ComplaintTicket imageModel)
        {
            if (imageModel.ImageFile != null)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
                fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                imageModel.Attachment = "~/Image/" + fileName;
                string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Image/");
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(folderPath))
                {
                    fileName = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
                    imageModel.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
                    fileName = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
                    imageModel.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
                }
            }
            //db.ComplaintTicket.Add(imageModel);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            //ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }
}
```

> Modal Class

```
public partial class ComplaintTicket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Attachment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Ministry { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also my code works fine when I changed HttpPostedFile to HttpPostedFileBase. I can't upvote you because my reputation is below 15

Answer (score 3):

Please check this example.

**Note:** in your question maybe you forget the `form tag` when the file is uploaded ,form tag is required, with the required attributes `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`.

Apart for this you can upload upload file using `jquery/ajax` or some another `plugin`.

`cshtml` markup:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ComplaintTicket</h4>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "ComplaintTicket", FormMethod.Post,
                              new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { 
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attachment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ministry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ministry, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ministry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
public class ComplaintTicketController : Controller
{
    //CRUDDataComplaintsEntities db = new CRUDDataComplaintsEntities();
    //// GET: ComplaintTicket
    //public ActionResult Index()
    //{
    //    //var tickets = db.ComplaintsTickets.ToList();
    //    var tickets = (from x in db.ComplaintTicket
    //                   join a in db.mins on x.Ministry equals a.Id
    //                   select new TicketsIndexLists() { Id = x.Id, Title = x.Title, Message = x.Message, Attachment = x.Attachment, Name = a.Name }).ToList();
    //    return View(tickets);
    //}
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(ComplaintTicket imageModel,FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        try
        {
           // you can check with Request.Files.Count also
           // if(Request.Files.Count > 0) then your logic to save file
            if(imageModel.ImageFile!=null)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
                fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                imageModel.Attachment = "~/Image/" + fileName;
                fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
                imageModel.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
            }

            db.ComplaintTicket.Add(imageModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            //after save your return value
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance of `ComplaintTicket` to the `View` from the controller. In the `Add` controller method with `HttpGet` you can do this:

```c#
return View(new ComplaintTicket());
```

Instead of returning `View()`. This way the model passed to the view is not `null`.

Comment: Still getting the same error,  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Use the debugger and verify that `imageModel` and `imageModel.ImageFile` are not null.

Comment: Instead of the plain file input try `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageFile, new { type ="file" })`